# Sorting large server log files in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

Not sure where to ask this but:

I would like to create a Macros in excel to sort and color code server generated logs and color code them. I have 3,000+ lines of information in each text file.

Here's the snapshot of the log file:
[image]

When I put this into excel, it all get's jumbled up into one cell and I want to be able to sort each cell by

> `Request_path, count, Avg_bytes_sents, etc..`

Just like how it's sorted in the text document. I want to use marcos to sort it and make pivot tables but it looks out of wack and unorganized when I paste it into excel.

Is there anyway to sort it without actually copying each line manually inputting it into excel? It would take forever to copy 10k worth of log executions....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have excel 2010 or newer just use the in-built Text to Columns function specifying the | as the separator?

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1786-excel-split-text-by-space.html

Alternatively, something like this should work:

```
Sub Import_Log_File()
    Dim Tmp as String
    Dim L as Integer, Cur_Row as Integer, Cur_Col as Integer
    Tmp = Range("A1").Value
    For L = 9 to Len(Tmp)
        If Right(Left(Tmp,L),9) = "Detailed:" Then
                Tmp = right(Tmp,Len(Tmp)-L)
                Exit For
        End If
    Next L
    L = 1
    Cur_Row = 1
    Cur_Col = 0
    Do
        If Right(Left(Tmp,L),1) = "|" or Right(Left(Tmp,L),1) ="+" Then
                If Cur_Col <> 7 Then
                        Cur_Col = Cur_Col + 1
                    Else
                        Cur_Col = 0
                        Cur_Row = Cur_Row + 1
                End If
                Cells(Cur_Row,Cur_Col) = Left(Tmp, L - 1)
                Tmp = Right(Tmp,Len(Tmp)-L)
                L = 1
            Else
                L =L + 1
        End If
    While L < Len(Tmp)
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, I should add that if you wish to copy/paste the above, you will need to replace all the Quotations, as I have written on my iPhone and know that they don’t work when pasted into VBA.

Comment: I edited the answer to fix the smart-quote issue - code should be able to be copy/pasted now.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance as I am not familiar with VBAs. Do I create a new macro and just paste this code into it and delete the original?

Comment: Apologies, from your question I assumed you were familiar with VBA. Yes create a Macro Enabled workbook (SaveAs) then press Alt+F11 to open the VBA editor. Add a New Module and then paste this code into the module (I have edited it to include all necessary info now. You can then create a shape on the Worksheet that you wish to paste your log file text into and right click it and assign macro. Then choose this Macro from the menu...After that, simply paste your txt file contents into the first cell and press the button (shape).

Answer (score 0):

I would write a script to convert this text file to a csv, then I would open the csv with Excel.

This Python script will copy each line into a csv, so you would need to clean up the header by yourself.

Change the filename ‘serverlog.txt’ to be the file you want to parse.

```
output = open("output.csv", "w")
for line in open("serverlog.txt"):
    parts = (s.strip() for s in line.split("|"))
    output.write(",".join(parts[1:-1]))
```

Comment: Not familiar with Python scripting. How would I execute the .py file?

Comment: Introducing a script language which is not part of any common operating system and which apparently OP is not familiar with, just to replace a "|" with a comma?? @Sercho already posted how to make a "|" the separator when importing the text file into Excel, without any conversion beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Use Power Query, no need for any coding at all. Can import multiple files at once,  regardless of number of rows of data